# Selecting arbitrary subsets of dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

Is there a way to select arbitrary date subsets in a Pandas dataframe? So that if I have the following:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
df
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
2013-01-06 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
```

I would like to do, for example:

```
my_selection = ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-05']]
my_df = df.loc[my_selection]
my_df
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need convert dates to `datetime`s for match `DatetimeIndex`:

```
my_selection = ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-05']
my_df = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(my_selection)]
print (my_df)
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
```

---

If possible some dates are not in `DatetimeIndex`:

```
my_selection = ['2013-01-21', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-05']

my_df = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(my_selection)]
```

> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
>   KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

```
my_df = df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(my_selection))
print (my_df)
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-21       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
```

Or use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
my_df = df.loc[df.index.intersection(pd.to_datetime(my_selection))]
print (my_df)
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
```